# Log info to check returned json, and found out it return with a header, makes json_decode unable to work

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am using laravel framework to create an api, below is my code

In Helper:

```
public static function checkValid($phone_number, $product){
        $client = Client::where('phone_number',$phone_number)->first();
        $product = Product::where('name',$product)->first();
        $checking = ClientProduct::where('client_id',$client->id)->where('product_id',$product->id)->first();
        if(!empty($checking)){
            return response('{"error" : 1, "message" : "This phone_number already been register, username: '.$checking->username.'"}',401);
        }
```

In Testing Controller

```
$res = Helper::checkValid($request->phone_number,$request->product);
Log::info($res);
```

Result of Log

> [2016-05-31 01:12:17] local.INFO: HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> {"error" : 1, "message" : "This phone_number already been register,
>   username: asd"}

because the `$res` have header inside, I can't use `json_decode($res)` to get the error message.

Anyone know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to fix the problem,just return with a string or array instead of json in Helper, because in Controller it does not need a header